# Can we make a stake pool where we stake SPL tokens instead of SOL

Tags: solana

Is it possible to stake SPL token in a stake pool and write a mechanism for custom reward mechanism instead of staking actual SOL.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly! Please take a look at some of these reference implementations for yield farming, in particular, the vault: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/farms#vaults

As you've correctly noted, the SPL stake-pool program at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/stake-pool is specific to SOL, and cannot be used to stake other tokens.